# Writing Large Image Sprite Sheet

Tags: javax.imageio, sprite-sheet

I am trying to make a Sprite Sheet by combining an animation cycle into one image and writing it into one Image.  However, I get this exception: "Maximum supported image dimension is 65500 pixels".  This is 2 questions.

1.) What is image dimension 65500 pixels?  Does that mean either dimension (width or height) needs to be under 65500, or that the total area (width*height) needs to be under 65500 pixels?

2.) Is there a way to get around this?  I need a sprite sheet of width: 426,667 pixels and of height: 240 pixels (for a total area of 102,400,000 pixels).  Right now I am saving it as a jpeg file.  Are there different dimension limits for writing different file types?

Here is the code I have:

```
int length = 1000;
BufferedImage sheet = new BufferedImage(1280*length/3, 720/3, 
BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    String path = i+".jpg";
    try {
        load = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(path));
        sheet.getGraphics().drawImage(load, i*1280/3, 0, null);
    }catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to load "+path);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
try {
    ImageIO.write(sheet, "jpg", new File("spriteSheet"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Failed to write spriteSheet.");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
this.stop();
```

Comment: You mention an exception. It's generally a good thing to post the (relevant parts of the) stack trace as text, in your question. This will help people better understand your problem.

Comment: PS: Yes, the JPEG format has a maximum size of 65 535 in each dimension (probably rounded to 65 500 by the implementation for some reason), as the width/height are stored as unsigned 16 bit values. Other formats have different limits. A sprite sheet is probably better stored as PNG anyway. But making your image narrower but taller should also fix the problem.

Comment: I thought, "Maximum supported image dimension is 65500 pixels" was the relevant part of the stack trace?  What other parts should I be posting?

Comment: PS: Thanks! It works now that I made the sheet more narrow (100x10 for the images).  There was a strange bug where the bottom row was blank, but it was fixed by a simple call of drawing a subimage of that area during the sheet creation.

Comment: Glad you made it work! What I meant about stack trace, is... The stack trace (ie. the output of e.printStackTrace() ). With methods and line numbers. You have just posted an error message.